# XAMPP: "httpd.exe - Entry Point Not Found" Error

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

Im trying to configure xampp in windows server 2012RT 64-bit.
I downloaded latest version of xampp(**xampp-win32-7.0.1-0**).
I am using oracle 11gR2 version, so I downloaded oracle instant client 11_2 (64-bit).
I enabled extension for oracle in php.ini file

```
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
```

And restarted xampp server, I got error like this,

[image: XAMPP Error]

Comment: ever find the solution?

Comment: You cannot use 64-bit drivers in 32-bit PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Step to connect Oracle through PDO at XAMPP

1 - Download the Oracle Instant Client (ZIP) from Oracle Site

2 - Extract the Oracle Instant Client into C:\ or Desktop

3 - Copy all files and folders from Oracle Instant Client to C:\XAMPP\APACHE\BIN\

4 - Open the PHP.ini into C:\XAMPP\PHP\ and removing the semicolon from ";extension=php_pdo_oci.dll" and then save and close the file

4 - Restart Apache and Enjoy it

Answer (score 0):

**

**Problem**:

**
I have got this problem when i have unexpectedly deleted all of my users from XAMPP root and localHost.
1.Apache server Error: Entry Point Not Found:
2. procedure entry point free could not be located in the dynamic link library
c:\xampp\apache\bin\libapriconv-1.dll

**Solution:**

1. uninstall Visual C++ 2015 redistributable.
2. download from microsoft Visual C++ 2015 redistributable and install.
   Note: you will found error X080070666 (Not install because your machine has some new version of visual C++ distributable like 2017 and 2019) so uninstall these new versions.
3. Now install Visual c++ 2015 distributale
4. now download and install visual c++ 2017 and Visual C++ 2019 if your machine has previously has these distributalbe.
5. Now Reboot Your Computer
6. Enjoy....

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem, following solution works for me.

1. Download portable xampp.
2. Extract the folder and copy httpd.exe file from apache/bin folder and paste in your installed xampp/apache/bin folder.
3. Re-open xampp control panel and start apache.

Hope it works for you too.